# How to put part of php code into wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, html, wordpress, shortcode

I have a wordpress plugin that allows me to upload user avatars. I'm trying to take a piece of code that shows the thumbnail and put it in a shortcode so that I can place the thumbnail anywhere on the site.

I am relatively new to php, I know how to start a shortcode for wordpress but I don't know how to structure the shortcode to host php. Would anyone be kind enough to give me advice?

The code below php is the original of the plugin file:

```
<?php
/**
 * Defines all profile and upload settings.
 *
 * @package    One User Avatar
 * @author     Bangbay Siboliban
 * @author     Flippercode
 * @author     ProfilePress
 * @author     One Designs
 * @copyright  2013-2014 Bangbay Siboliban
 * @copyright  2014-2020 Flippercode
 * @copyright  2020-2021 ProfilePress
 * @copyright  2021 One Designs
 * @version    2.3.9
 */

class WP_User_Avatar {
    /**
     * Constructor
     * @since 1.8
     * @uses string $pagenow
     * @uses bool $show_avatars
     * @uses object $wpua_admin
     * @uses bool $wpua_allow_upload
     * @uses add_action()
     * @uses add_filterI]()
     * @uses is_admin()
     * @uses is_user_logged_in()
     * @uses wpua_is_author_or_above()
     * @uses wpua_is_menu_page()
     */
    public function __construct() {
        global $pagenow, $show_avatars, $wpua_admin, $wpua_allow_upload;

        // Add WPUA to profile for users with permission
        if ( $this->wpua_is_author_or_above() || ( 1 == (bool) $wpua_allow_upload && is_user_logged_in() ) ) {
            // Profile functions and scripts
            add_action( 'show_user_profile', array( $this, 'wpua_maybe_show_user_profile' ) );
            add_action( 'edit_user_profile', array( $this, 'wpua_maybe_show_user_profile' ) );

            add_action( 'personal_options_update',  array( $this, 'wpua_action_process_option_update' ) );
            add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', array( $this, 'wpua_action_process_option_update' ) );

            add_action( 'user_new_form', array( $this, 'wpua_action_show_user_profile' ) );
            add_action( 'user_register', array( $this, 'wpua_action_process_option_update' ) );

            add_filter( 'user_profile_picture_description', array( $this, 'wpua_description_show_user_profile' ), PHP_INT_MAX, 2 );

            // Admin scripts
            $pages = array( 'profile.php', 'options-discussion.php', 'user-edit.php', 'user-new.php', 'admin.php' );

            if ( in_array( $pagenow, $pages ) || $wpua_admin->wpua_is_menu_page() ) {
                add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', array( $this, 'wpua_media_upload_scripts' ) );
            }

            // Front pages
            if ( ! is_admin() ) {
                add_action( 'show_user_profile', array( 'wp_user_avatar', 'wpua_media_upload_scripts' ) );
                add_action( 'edit_user_profile', array( 'wp_user_avatar', 'wpua_media_upload_scripts' ) );
            }

            if ( ! $this->wpua_is_author_or_above() ) {
                // Upload errors
                add_action( 'user_profile_update_errors', array( $this, 'wpua_upload_errors' ), 10, 3 );

                // Prefilter upload size
                add_filter( 'wp_handle_upload_prefilter', array(  $this, 'wpua_handle_upload_prefilter' ) );
            }
        }

        add_filter( 'media_view_settings', array( $this, 'wpua_media_view_settings' ), 10, 1 );
    }

    /**
     * Avatars have no parent posts
     *
     * @param array $settings
     *
     * @return array
     * @uses object $post
     * @uses bool $wpua_is_profile
     * @uses is_admin()
     * array $settings
     * @since 1.8.4
     */
    public function wpua_media_view_settings( $settings ) {
        global $post, $wpua_is_profile;

        // Get post ID so not to interfere with media uploads
        $post_id = is_object( $post ) ? $post->ID : 0;

        // Don't use post ID on front pages if there's a WPUA uploader
        $settings['post']['id'] = ( ! is_admin() && 1 == $wpua_is_profile ) ? 0 : $post_id;

        return $settings;
    }

    /**
     * Media Uploader
     * @since 1.4
     * @param object $user
     * @uses object $current_user
     * @uses string $mustache_admin
     * @uses string $pagenow
     * @uses object $post
     * @uses bool $show_avatars
     * @uses object $wp_user_avatar
     * @uses object $wpua_admin
     * @uses object $wpua_functions
     * @uses bool $wpua_is_profile
     * @uses int $wpua_upload_size_limit
     * @uses get_user_by()
     * @uses wp_enqueue_script()
     * @uses wp_enqueue_media()
     * @uses wp_enqueue_style()
     * @uses wp_localize_script()
     * @uses wp_max_upload_size()
     * @uses wpua_get_avatar_original()
     * @uses wpua_is_author_or_above()
     * @uses wpua_is_menu_page()
     */
    public static function wpua_media_upload_scripts( $user = '' ) {
        global  $current_user,
                $mustache_admin,
                $pagenow,
                $plugin_page,
                $post,
                $show_avatars,
                $wp_user_avatar,
                $wpua_force_file_uploader,
                $wpua_admin,
                $wpua_functions,
                $wpua_is_profile,
                $wpua_upload_size_limit;

        // This is a profile page
        $wpua_is_profile = 1;

        $user = ( $pagenow == 'user-edit.php' && isset( $_GET['user_id'] ) ) ? get_user_by( 'id', absint( $_GET['user_id'] ) ) : $current_user;

        wp_enqueue_style( 'wp-user-avatar', WPUA_CSS_URL . 'wp-user-avatar.css', '', WPUA_VERSION );

        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

        if ( ( $wp_user_avatar->wpua_is_author_or_above() && ! $wpua_force_file_uploader ) || 'options-discussion.php' == $pagenow ) {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'admin-bar' );
            wp_enqueue_media( array( 'post' => $post ) );
            wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-user-avatar', WPUA_JS_URL . 'wp-user-avatar.js', array( 'jquery', 'media-editor' ), WPUA_VERSION, true );
        } else {
            wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-user-avatar', WPUA_JS_URL . 'wp-user-avatar-user.js', array( 'jquery' ), WPUA_VERSION, true );
        }

        // Admin scripts
        if ( 'options-discussion.php' == $pagenow || $wpua_admin->wpua_is_menu_page() ) {
            wp_localize_script( 'wp-user-avatar', 'wpua_custom', array(
                'avatar_thumb' => $mustache_admin,
            ) );
        }

        if (
            'options-discussion.php' == $pagenow
            ||
            $wpua_admin->wpua_is_menu_page()
            ||
            (
                'admin.php' == $pagenow
                &&
                isset( $plugin_page )
                &&
                'wp-user-avatar-library' == $plugin_page
            )
        ) {
            // Settings control
            wp_enqueue_script( 'wp-user-avatar-admin', WPUA_JS_URL . 'wp-user-avatar-admin.js', array( 'wp-user-avatar' ), WPUA_VERSION, true );
            wp_localize_script( 'wp-user-avatar-admin', 'wpua_admin', array(
                'upload_size_limit' => $wpua_upload_size_limit,
                'max_upload_size'   => wp_max_upload_size(),
            ) );
        } else {
            // Original user avatar
            $avatar_medium_src = 1 == (bool) $show_avatars ? $wpua_functions->wpua_get_avatar_original( $user->user_email, 'medium' ) : includes_url() . 'images/blank.gif';

            wp_localize_script( 'wp-user-avatar', 'wpua_custom', array(
                'avatar_thumb' => $avatar_medium_src,
            ) );
        }
    }

    public static function wpua_core_show_user_profile( $user ) {
        global  $blog_id,
                $current_user,
                $show_avatars,
                $wpdb,
                $wp_user_avatar,
                $wpua_force_file_uploader,
                $wpua_edit_avatar,
                $wpua_functions,
                $wpua_upload_size_limit_with_units;

        $has_wp_user_avatar = has_wp_user_avatar( @$user->ID );

        // Get WPUA attachment ID
        $wpua = get_user_meta( @$user->ID, $wpdb->get_blog_prefix( $blog_id ) . 'user_avatar', true );

        // Show remove button if WPUA is set
        $hide_remove = ! $has_wp_user_avatar ? 'wpua-hide' : '';

        // Hide image tags if show avatars is off
        $hide_images = ! $has_wp_user_avatar && 0 == (bool) $show_avatars ? 'wpua-no-avatars' : '';

        // If avatars are enabled, get original avatar image or show blank
        $avatar_medium_src = 1 == (bool) $show_avatars ? $wpua_functions->wpua_get_avatar_original( @$user->user_email, 'medium' ) : includes_url() . 'images/blank.gif';

        // Check if user has wp_user_avatar, if not show image from above
        $avatar_medium = $has_wp_user_avatar ? get_wp_user_avatar_src( $user->ID, 'medium' ) : $avatar_medium_src;

        // Check if user has wp_user_avatar, if not show image from above
        $avatar_thumbnail     = $has_wp_user_avatar ? get_wp_user_avatar_src( $user->ID, 96 ) : $avatar_medium_src;
        $edit_attachment_link = esc_url( add_query_arg( array(
            'post'   => $wpua,
            'action' => 'edit',
        ), admin_url( 'post.php' ) ) );
        ?>

        <input type="hidden" name="wp-user-avatar" id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wp-user-avatar' : 'wp-user-avatar-existing' ) ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $wpua ); ?>" />

        <?php
        if ( $wp_user_avatar->wpua_is_author_or_above() && ! $wpua_force_file_uploader ) :
            // Button to launch Media Uploader
            ?>

            <p id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wpua-add-button' : 'wpua-add-button-existing' ); ?>">
                <button
                    type="button"
                    class="button"
                    id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wpua-add' : 'wpua-add-existing' ); ?>"
                    name="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wpua-add' : 'wpua-add-existing' ); ?>"
                    data-title="<?php printf(
                        /* translators: user display name */
                        __( 'Choose Image: %s', 'one-user-avatar' ),
                        ( ! empty( $user->display_name ) ? esc_attr( $user->display_name ) : '' )
                    ); ?>"
                >
                    <?php esc_html_e( 'Choose Image', 'one-user-avatar' ); ?>
                </button>
            </p>

            <?php
        elseif ( ! $wp_user_avatar->wpua_is_author_or_above() || $wpua_force_file_uploader ) :
            // Upload button
            ?>

            <p id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wpua-upload-button' : 'wpua-upload-button-existing' ); ?>">
                <input name="wpua-file" id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wpua-file' : 'wpua-file-existing' ); ?>" type="file" />

                <button type="submit" class="button" id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wpua-upload' : 'wpua-upload-existing' ); ?>" name="submit" value="<?php esc_html_e( 'Upload', 'one-user-avatar' ); ?>">
                    <?php esc_html_e( 'Upload', 'one-user-avatar' ); ?>
                </button>
            </p>

            <p id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wpua-upload-messages' : 'wpua-upload-messages-existing' ); ?>">
                <span id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( $user == 'add-new-user') ? 'wpua-max-upload' : 'wpua-max-upload-existing' ); ?>" class="description">
                    <?php
                    printf(
                        /* translators: file size in KB */
                        __( 'Maximum upload file size: %s.', 'one-user-avatar' ),
                        esc_html( $wpua_upload_size_limit_with_units . 'KB' )
                    );
                    ?>
                </span>

                <span id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wpua-allowed-files' : 'wpua-allowed-files-existing' ); ?>" class="description">
                    <?php
                    printf(
                        /* translators: allowed file extensions */
                        __( 'Allowed Files: %s', 'one-user-avatar' ),
                        '<code>jpg jpeg png gif</code>'
                    );
                    ?>
                </span>
            </p>

            <?php
        endif;
        ?>

        <div id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wpua-images' : 'wpua-images-existing' ); ?>" class="<?php echo esc_attr( $hide_images ); ?>">
            <p id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wpua-preview' : 'wpua-preview-existing' ); ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $avatar_medium ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( __( 'Original Size', 'one-user-avatar' ) ); ?>" />

                <span class="description"><?php esc_html_e( 'Original Size', 'one-user-avatar' ); ?></span>
            </p>

            <p id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wpua-thumbnail' : 'wpua-thumbnail-existing' ); ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo esc_url( $avatar_thumbnail ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( __( 'Thumbnail', 'one-user-avatar' ) ); ?>"/>

                <span class="description"><?php esc_html_e( 'Thumbnail', 'one-user-avatar' ); ?></span>
            </p>

            <p id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wpua-remove-button' : 'wpua-remove-button-existing' ); ?>" class="<?php echo esc_attr( $hide_remove ); ?>">
                <button type="button" class="button" id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wpua-remove' : 'wpua-remove-existing' ); ?>" name="wpua-remove"><?php esc_html_e( 'Remove Image', 'one-user-avatar' ); ?></button>
            </p>

            <p id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wpua-undo-button' : 'wpua-undo-button-existing' ); ?>">
                <button type="button" class="button" id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wpua-undo' : 'wpua-undo-existing' ); ?>" name="wpua-undo"><?php esc_html_e( 'Undo', 'one-user-avatar' ); ?></button>
            </p>
        </div>

        <?php
    }

    /**
     * Add to edit user profile
     *
     * @param object $user
     *
     * @since 1.4
     * @uses int $blog_id
     * @uses object $current_user
     * @uses bool $show_avatars
     * @uses object $wpdb
     * @uses object $wp_user_avatar
     * @uses bool $wpua_edit_avatar
     * @uses object $wpua_functions
     * @uses string $wpua_upload_size_limit_with_units
     * @uses add_query_arg()
     * @uses admin_url()
     * @uses do_action()
     * @uses get_blog_prefix()
     * @uses get_user_meta()
     * @uses get_wp_user_avatar_src()
     * @uses has_wp_user_avatar()
     * @uses is_admin()
     * @uses wpua_author()
     * @uses wpua_get_avatar_original()
     * @uses wpua_is_author_or_above()
     */
    public static function wpua_action_show_user_profile( $user ) {
        $is_admin = is_admin() ? '_admin' : '';

        do_action( 'wpua_before_avatar' . $is_admin );

        self::wpua_core_show_user_profile( $user );

        do_action( 'wpua_after_avatar' . $is_admin );
    }

    public function wpua_maybe_show_user_profile( $user ) {
        if ( is_admin() ) {
            return;
        }

        $this->wpua_action_show_user_profile( $user );
    }

    // setting defaults for the filter callback fixes an error like https://wordpress.org/support/topic/error-missing-argument-2-for-wp_user_avatarclosure
    // see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37779680/missing-argument-2-for-a-custom-function
    public function wpua_description_show_user_profile( $description = '', $profileuser = null ) {
        ob_start();

        echo wp_specialchars_decode( wp_kses(
            '<style>.user-profile-picture > td > .avatar { display: none; }</style>',
            array(
                'style' => array(),
            )
        ) );

        self::wpua_core_show_user_profile( $profileuser );

        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    /**
     * Add upload error messages
     * @since 1.7.1
     * @param array $errors
     * @param bool $update
     * @param object $user
     * @uses int $wpua_upload_size_limit
     * @uses add()
     * @uses wp_upload_dir()
     */
    public static function wpua_upload_errors( $errors, $update, $user ) {
        global $wpua_upload_size_limit;

        if ( $update && ! empty( $_FILES['wpua-file'] ) ) {
            $file = $_FILES['wpua-file'];
            $size = isset( $file['size'] ) ? absint( $file['size'] )             : 0;
            $type = isset( $file['type'] ) ? sanitize_mime_type( $file['type'] ) : '';

            $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

            // Allow only JPG, GIF, PNG
            if ( ! empty( $type ) && ! preg_match( '/(jpe?g|gif|png)$/i', $type ) ) {
                $errors->add( 'wpua_file_type', __( 'This file is not an image. Please try another.', 'one-user-avatar' ) );
            }

            // Upload size limit
            if ( ! empty( $size ) && $size > $wpua_upload_size_limit ) {
                $errors->add( 'wpua_file_size', __( 'Memory exceeded. Please try another smaller file.', 'one-user-avatar' ) );
            }

            // Check if directory is writeable
            if ( ! is_writeable( $upload_dir['path'] ) ) {
                $errors->add( 'wpua_file_directory', sprintf(
                    /* translators: directory path */
                    __( 'Unable to create directory %s. Is its parent directory writable by the server?', 'one-user-avatar' ), $upload_dir['path']
                ) );
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Set upload size limit
     * @since 1.5
     * @param object $file
     * @uses int $wpua_upload_size_limit
     * @uses add_action()
     * @return object $file
     */
    public function wpua_handle_upload_prefilter( $file ) {
        global $wpua_upload_size_limit;

        $size = absint( $file['size'] );

        if ( ! empty( $size ) && $size > $wpua_upload_size_limit ) {
            /**
             * Error handling that only appears on front pages
             * @since 1.7
             */
            function wpua_file_size_error( $errors, $update, $user ) {
                $errors->add( 'wpua_file_size', __( 'Memory exceeded. Please try another smaller file.', 'one-user-avatar' ) );
            }

            add_action( 'user_profile_update_errors', 'wpua_file_size_error', 10, 3 );

            return;
        }

        return $file;
    }

    /**
     * Update user meta
     * @since 1.4
     * @param int $user_id
     * @uses int $blog_id
     * @uses object $post
     * @uses object $wpdb
     * @uses object $wp_user_avatar
     * @uses bool $wpua_resize_crop
     * @uses int $wpua_resize_h
     * @uses bool $wpua_resize_upload
     * @uses int $wpua_resize_w
     * @uses add_post_meta()
     * @uses delete_metadata()
     * @uses get_blog_prefix()
     * @uses is_wp_error()
     * @uses update_post_meta()
     * @uses update_user_meta()
     * @uses wp_delete_attachment()
     * @uses wp_generate_attachment_metadata()
     * @uses wp_get_image_editor()
     * @uses wp_handle_upload()
     * @uses wp_insert_attachment()
     * @uses WP_Query()
     * @uses wp_read_image_metadata()
     * @uses wp_reset_query()
     * @uses wp_update_attachment_metadata()
     * @uses wp_upload_dir()
     * @uses wpua_is_author_or_above()
     * @uses object $wpua_admin
     * @uses wpua_has_gravatar()
     */
    public static function wpua_action_process_option_update( $user_id ) {
        global  $blog_id,
                $post,
                $wpdb,
                $wp_user_avatar,
                $wpua_force_file_uploader,
                $wpua_resize_crop,
                $wpua_resize_h,
                $wpua_resize_upload,
                $wpua_resize_w,
                $wpua_admin;

        // Check if user has publish_posts capability
        if ( $wp_user_avatar->wpua_is_author_or_above() && ! $wpua_force_file_uploader ) {
            $wpua_id = isset( $_POST['wp-user-avatar'] ) ? absint( $_POST['wp-user-avatar'] ) : 0;

            // Remove old attachment postmeta
            delete_metadata( 'post', null, '_wp_attachment_wp_user_avatar', $user_id, true );

            // Create new attachment postmeta
            add_post_meta( $wpua_id, '_wp_attachment_wp_user_avatar', $user_id );

            // Update usermeta
            update_user_meta( $user_id, $wpdb->get_blog_prefix( $blog_id ) . 'user_avatar', $wpua_id );
        } else {
            // Remove attachment info if avatar is blank
            if ( isset( $_POST['wp-user-avatar'] ) && empty( $_POST['wp-user-avatar'] ) ) {
                // Delete other uploads by user
                $q = array(
                    'author'         => $user_id,
                    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
                    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
                    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
                    'meta_query'     => array(
                        array(
                            'key'     => '_wp_attachment_wp_user_avatar',
                            'value'   => "",
                            'compare' => '!='
                        ),
                    ),
                );

                $avatars_wp_query = new WP_Query( $q );

                while( $avatars_wp_query->have_posts() ) {
                    $avatars_wp_query->the_post();

                    wp_delete_attachment( $post->ID );
                }

                wp_reset_query();

                // Remove attachment postmeta
                delete_metadata( 'post', null, '_wp_attachment_wp_user_avatar', $user_id, true );

                // Remove usermeta
                update_user_meta( $user_id, $wpdb->get_blog_prefix( $blog_id ) . 'user_avatar', '' );
            }

            // Create attachment from upload
            if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) && $_POST['submit'] && ! empty( $_FILES['wpua-file'] ) ) {
                $file = $_FILES['wpua-file'];
                $name = isset( $file['name'] ) ? sanitize_file_name( $file['name'] ) : '';
                $type = isset( $file['type'] ) ? sanitize_mime_type( $file['type'] ) : '';
                $file = wp_handle_upload( $file, array(
                    'test_form' => false,
                ) );

                if ( isset( $file['url'] ) ) {
                    if ( ! empty( $type ) && preg_match( '/(jpe?g|gif|png)$/i' , $type ) ) {
                        // Resize uploaded image
                        if ( 1 == (bool) $wpua_resize_upload ) {
                            // Original image
                            $uploaded_image = wp_get_image_editor( $file['file'] );

                            // Check for errors
                            if ( ! is_wp_error( $uploaded_image ) ) {
                                // Resize image
                                $uploaded_image->resize( $wpua_resize_w, $wpua_resize_h, $wpua_resize_crop );

                                // Save image
                                $uploaded_image->save( $file['file'] );
                            }
                        }

                        // Break out file info
                        $name_parts = pathinfo( $name );
                        $name       = trim( substr( $name, 0, -( 1 + strlen( $name_parts['extension'] ) ) ) );
                        $url        = $file['url'];
                        $file       = $file['file'];
                        $title      = $name;

                        // Use image exif/iptc data for title if possible
                        if ( $image_meta = @wp_read_image_metadata( $file ) ) {
                            if ( trim( $image_meta['title'] ) && ! is_numeric( sanitize_title( $image_meta['title'] ) ) ) {
                                $title = $image_meta['title'];
                            }
                        }

                        // Construct the attachment array
                        $attachment = array(
                            'guid'           => $url,
                            'post_mime_type' => $type,
                            'post_title'     => $title,
                            'post_content'   => '',
                        );

                        // This should never be set as it would then overwrite an existing attachment
                        if ( isset( $attachment['ID'] ) ) {
                            unset( $attachment['ID'] );
                        }

                        // Save the attachment metadata
                        $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file );

                        if ( ! is_wp_error( $attachment_id ) ) {
                            // Delete other uploads by user
                            $q = array(
                                'author'         => $user_id,
                                'post_type'      => 'attachment',
                                'post_status'    => 'inherit',
                                'posts_per_page' => '-1',
                                'meta_query'     => array(
                                    array(
                                        'key'     => '_wp_attachment_wp_user_avatar',
                                        'value'   => '',
                                        'compare' => '!=',
                                    ),
                                ),
                            );

                            $avatars_wp_query = new WP_Query( $q );

                            while ( $avatars_wp_query->have_posts() ){
                                $avatars_wp_query->the_post();

                                wp_delete_attachment($post->ID);
                            }

                            wp_reset_query();

                            wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $file ) );

                            // Remove old attachment postmeta
                            delete_metadata( 'post', null, '_wp_attachment_wp_user_avatar', $user_id, true );

                            // Create new attachment postmeta
                            update_post_meta( $attachment_id, '_wp_attachment_wp_user_avatar', $user_id );

                            // Update usermeta
                            update_user_meta( $user_id, $wpdb->get_blog_prefix( $blog_id ) . 'user_avatar', $attachment_id );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check attachment is owned by user
     * @since 1.4
     * @param int $attachment_id
     * @param int $user_id
     * @param bool $wpua_author
     * @uses get_post()
     * @return bool
     */
    private function wpua_author( $attachment_id, $user_id, $wpua_author = 0 ) {
        $attachment = get_post( $attachment_id );

        if ( ! empty( $attachment ) && $attachment->post_author == $user_id ) {
            $wpua_author = true;
        }

        return (bool) $wpua_author;
    }

    /**
     * Check if current user has at least Author privileges
     * @since 1.8.5
     * @uses current_user_can()
     * @uses apply_filters()
     * @return bool
     */
    public function wpua_is_author_or_above() {
        $is_author_or_above = (
            current_user_can( 'edit_published_posts' )  &&
            current_user_can( 'upload_files' )          &&
            current_user_can( 'publish_posts')          &&
            current_user_can( 'delete_published_posts')
        ) ? true : false;

        /**
         * Filter Author privilege check
         * @since 1.9.2
         * @param bool $is_author_or_above
         */
        return (bool) apply_filters( 'wpua_is_author_or_above', $is_author_or_above );
    }
}

/**
 * Initialize WP_User_Avatar
 * @since 1.8
 */
function wpua_init() {
    global $wp_user_avatar;

    if ( ! isset( $wp_user_avatar ) ) {
        $wp_user_avatar = new WP_User_Avatar();
    }

    return $wp_user_avatar;
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpua_init' );
```

The piece of code I want to put in the shortcode is this below, basically it shows the thumbnail. I tried to structure a shortcode in functions.php with this, but I was unsuccessful.

```
<p id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wpua-thumbnail' : 'wpua-thumbnail-existing' ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( $avatar_thumbnail ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( __( 'Thumbnail', 'one-user-avatar' ) ); ?>"/>

<span class="description"><?php esc_html_e( 'Thumbnail', 'one-user-avatar' ); ?></span>
</p>
```

Here's what I did:

```
// Shortcode to output custom PHP
function demo_shortcode() {
?><img src="<?php echo $avatar_thumbnail; ?>" alt="" /><?php

global 
    $current_user,
    $show_avatars,
    $wpdb,
    $wp_user_avatar,
    $wpua_functions;

        // If avatars are enabled, get original avatar image or show blank
        $avatar_medium_src = 1 == (bool) $show_avatars ? $wpua_functions->wpua_get_avatar_original( @$user->user_email, 'medium' ) : includes_url() . 'images/blank.gif';

        // Check if user has wp_user_avatar, if not show image from above
        $avatar_thumbnail = $has_wp_user_avatar ? get_wp_user_avatar_src( $user->ID, 96 ) : $avatar_medium_src;

return $avatar_medium_src;

} 
add_shortcode('demo', 'demo_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the general function that you are looking for.

I cannot promise it will work because I don't have that plugin available.

The original function you are referencing assumes that a `$user` object is being passed to it, but I'm not seeing that in your implementation, so I'm just going to assume the current logged in user, if they exist.

I pulled all of the globals that I could find. There's also a bunch of functions that are from the plugin that I can't guarantee will be loaded/available, but you should at least get an error than.

Rename the function as you need to, obviously.

```
function stuff() {
    // The first is a WordPress global, the other two are from the plugin, apparently
    global $current_user, $show_avatars, $wpua_functions;

    // Blindly assume we're talking about the current user
    $user = $current_user;

    // Call one of the plugin's functions
    $has_wp_user_avatar = has_wp_user_avatar(@$user->ID);

    // Why "1==(boo)"? Not sure who wrote that, but I'm leaving it in.
    $avatar_medium_src = 1 == (bool)$show_avatars ? $wpua_functions->wpua_get_avatar_original($user->user_email, 'medium') : includes_url().'images/blank.gif';

    $avatar_thumbnail = $has_wp_user_avatar ? get_wp_user_avatar_src($user->ID, 96) : $avatar_medium_src;
    ?>
    <p id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wpua-thumbnail' : 'wpua-thumbnail-existing' ); ?>"><img src="<?php echo esc_url( $avatar_thumbnail ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( __( 'Thumbnail', 'one-user-avatar' ) ); ?>"/>

        <span class="description"><?php esc_html_e( 'Thumbnail', 'one-user-avatar' ); ?></span>
    </p>
<?php
}
```

Comment: It was about 3 days that I played and googled for a solution, the situation had become frustrating. Your solution works just the way I wanted it. I thank you infinitely.

Comment: Hi again Chris. Since you have been of tremendous help and provided the solution to my problem, will you help me understand where I am wrong?

I'm trying to do exactly the same thing, this time I have to bring back several different shortcodes, including, upload image, select image and update button.

Comment: @EmanueleDaniele, do you have a new question here that you can reference?

Comment: Hi Chris, I edited the post. I have added a new problem that I am facing to the final part of the post. There is the message indicating the part I am editing.

Comment: @EmanueleDaniele, because you had accepted an answer, the generally preferred method is to open a new question, referencing the old one, and explain the new problem, even if it is more of an update of the existing one. This allows everyone a fresh context for the problem

Comment: Update: Thanks always for your help. I posted a new question at this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70354425/php-function-inside-wordpress-shortcode